# Libreoffice convert to pdf date format language

Tags: linux, pdf, libreoffice, doc, date-conversion

I'm using `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf INPUTPATH --outdir OUTPUTPATH` to convert .doc files to .pdf files (linux machine). But somehow the date format language is changes during this conversion...

In Word, the date is as follows: `1 maart 2020` (Dutch format). But after conversion, it shows up as either `1 March 2020` or `1 maart 20201 March 20201 maart 2020` but not the text of the Worddocument.

I've tried to convert files manually, and that works fine. Does anyone know if Libreoffice does some smart tricks in the background to recognize dates?

Comment: Did you try several different date formats, for example with test documents? What does the documentation say? What do LibreOffice's own forums reveal?

Comment: The .doc file is coming from another automated system, so i'm not directly able to change the date format...  Opening the document in Microsoft Word gives that it is in accordance with official (dutch) format

Comment: Did you research whether this "wonderful" Word can convert by a command line?